# Xamarin view - how to perform click?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

In my Xamarin application, when the user taps on the surface, I need to simulate sending click to the control under focus. With `Android.Views.View,` one could simply use `View.performClick().` How can I do something similar with `Xamarin.Forms.View?`

I also need to tab between focusable child controls based on user's action. How would one do that under Xamarin? Regards.